# Why is compiler option /MD added when compiling static library with nar-maven?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, maven, maven-nar-plugin

When setting `library.type` to `static`, and running `mvn -X clean compile`, the DEBUG output shows:

> [DEBUG] Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl' with arguments:
>   ''
>   '/c'
>   '/nologo'
>   '/EHsc'
>   '/DNDEBUG'
>   '/MD'
>   '/GR'
>   ...

including `/MD` which IMHO should not be present here. The same holds for compiling a test executable with `test.link` set to `static` and for compiling source files with `test.link` set to `shared`. The only case I would use `/MD` is when compiling an executable linked to shared libraries.

Even though maven produces a static library and the test is running without errors, setting the `_DLL` define inside the code mixes up my `__declspec(dllexport/dllimport)` macro for compiling shared libraries and is not necessary at all in the static case.

Can anybody give me a hint whether I'm overseeing something or this might be a plugin bug?

The example is taken and modified from the `it0010-lib-static` example from the `com.github.maven-nar` web site and the pom file stripped to the minimum:

pom.xml:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
         <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.5.1</version>
         <extensions>true</extensions>
         <configuration>
            <libraries>
               <library>
                  <type>static</type>
               </library>
            </libraries>
            <linker>
               <name>msvc</name>
            </linker>
            <tests>
               <test>
                  <name>HelloWorldTest</name>
                  <link>static</link>
               </test>
            </tests>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /MD and /MT compiler flags are controlled by the `<runtime/>` property which I was overseeing and which specifies the dependency of the produced artifacts on the dynamic C runtime libraries (CRTs)

While [checking the runtime type dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687620/how-to-check-the-runtime-library-type-of-a-binary-exe-generated-from-vc) of the produced lib and test executable for the different combinations of the (runtime | library.type) property pairs it became clear that:

(static | static) : /MT used, static lib, test and lib have no CRT dep 
(static | shared) : /MT used, dyn lib, test and lib have no CRT dep, test has rt dep on dll
(dynamic | static): /MD used, static lib, test and lib have CRT dep
(dynamic | shared): /MD used, dyn lib, test and lib have CRT dep, test has rt dep on dll

Remarks:

- the link.type for the test executable must always be the same as the library.type
- [Ability to build a shared library and tests using different runtime is still an open issue](https://recordnotfound.com/nar-maven-plugin-maven-nar-83376/issues)